# Converting Document Pages to Master Pages

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I want to convert active document pages to master pages. I have learned how to convert by watching this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o71TyJ1IkNE  Any possible way to convert using script.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script makes a new master based on current page:

```
app.panels.item('$ID/Pages').visible = true;
app.menuActions.itemByName("$ID/Save as Master").invoke();
```

If you have several pages you can iterate them this way:

```
app.panels.item('$ID/Pages').visible = true;

var pages = app.activeDocument.pages;

for (var i=0; i<pages.length; i++) {
    pages[i].select();
    app.menuActions.itemByName("$ID/Save as Master").invoke();
}
```

It works for spreads as well. (InDesign CC 2017)